# plot segment lines with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot segment lines with date data as x axis, and segment line shouldn't overlap with each other. However, there are some overlaps in the result figure.

Here is datafile named as **data.csv**

```
event_start,event_end,event_summary,posture
07:30,07:35,setting up desk,2
07:35,07:47,"fill water bottle, wash mug -> toilet",3
07:47,10:20,work( computer work + work discussion with office mate at desk),2
10:20,10:25,toilet,3
10:25,10:42,work,2
11:42,11:44,go find supervisor ,3
11:44,13:00,work (work discussion with supervisor at desk + computer work),2
13:00,13:30,toilet --> get lunch,2
13:30,14:00,Eat lunch,2
14:00,14:05,clean up,3
14:06,14:51,work (computer work + skype),2
14:51,14:59,toilet -> kitchen to fill ater bottle -> printing,3
14:59,16:31,work,2
16:31,16:42,toilet,3
16:42,17:15,work,2
```

Here is the code for plotting

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# plt.style.use('ggplot')

def plot_event(file_name, y_min=0, y_max=5):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    df['event_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_start'])
    df['event_end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_end'])

    xs = zip(df['event_start'], df['event_end'])
    ys = zip(df['posture'], df['posture'])
    plt.ylim(y_min, y_max)
    for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
        plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=linewidth)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = 'data.csv'
    y_min = 1
    y_max = 5
    linewidth = 8
    plot_event(file_name, y_min, y_max)
```

Here is the figure, and there are overlapping between different segments. It is wired because the date is not overlapped. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be caused by the lines default drawing style.

You may want to play with `solid_capstyle`, and `solid_joinstyle` parameters to `plt.plot()`. For example this:

```
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=linewidth, solid_capstyle='butt')
```

Will yeild:

[image]

You also might consider playing with linewidth as it adds to overlap, as well as other settings for line formatting which you can see in the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html?highlight=line#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_drawstyle)